# Python ElementTree XML Parsing with Multiple Answers

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am parsing movie.xml file generated by My Movies 5 to get genres for a movie.  Some movies have multiple genres, like:

```
-<Genres>
<Genre>Adventure</Genre>
<Genre>Comedy</Genre>
<Genre>Action</Genre>
...
...
</Genres>
```

How can I read it as a single variable
genres = genere1, genre2, genre3 ...

This is what I am doing, and it gives me just the first genre only:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('movie.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
Genre = tree.findtext("Genres/Genre")
```

The shortened movie.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--This file is created by My Movies (http://www.mymovies.dk)-->
<Title IsBoxSetParent="False" IsBoxSetChild="False">
  <ID>649</ID>
  <MediaType>Movie</MediaType>
  <LocalTitle>Six Days, Seven Nights</LocalTitle>
  <ProductionYear>1998</ProductionYear>
  <ReleaseDate>12/8/1998</ReleaseDate>
  <RunningTime>101</RunningTime>
  <TagLine />
  <Genres>
    <Genre>Adventure</Genre>
    <Genre>Comedy</Genre>
    <Genre>Action</Genre>
    <Genre>Romance</Genre>
  </Genres>
  <AudioTracks>
    <AudioTrack Language="English" Type="Dolby Digital" Channels="5.1" />
    <AudioTrack Language="French" Type="Dolby Digital" Channels="5.1" />
  </AudioTracks>
  <CheckSum>f98f43ba468b519bb7e78c15b7ab9cfa</CheckSum>
</Title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `findall()` call, use `map` to extract their text and `join` to create a string with all results, like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('movie.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
Genre = ', '.join(map(lambda e: e.text, tree.findall("Genres/Genre")))
print(Genre)
```

That yields:

```
Adventure, Comedy, Action, Romance
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, that is more elegant than one other way I came up with.

```
genre=""
for element in root.iter("Genre"):
        genre = genre + ", " + ("%s" % (element.text))
print genre
```

Produces the same:
`Adventure, Comedy, Action, Romance`